# different apps sharing core data through iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud

I have a project with two different targets - one for iPhone and one for iPad. I have both apps using the same ubiquity containers. If I run the same target on two different devices, iCloud syncing works fine. If I run the respective targets on different devices, there is no syncing. I expected there might be an extra step for getting this to work. But I've been unable to find any answers other than "specify the same ubiquity container for each app." Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same ubiquity container ID and the same NSPersistentStoreUbiquityName on all devices and in all apps

Comment: I mentioned I was using the same ubiquity container IDs. I can't seem to find NSPersistentStoreUbiquityName anywhere in the docs or headers.